# Darken SCSS function with transparent value

Tags: css, sass

I have a variable called $color0 assigned to a transparent value, like this:

```
$color0: transparent;
```

Per SCSS rules, if you use the darken/lighten functions to a variable it should do just that. So if I have a red color assigned to a red variable I should be able to darken it or lighten it like so:

```
$red: #ff0000;
.my-darker-color{
   color: darken($red, 20%); //produces #990000 
}
```

I can even use this function with an original semi-transparent value and it will still darken it! So say, for instance, I reduce the red color transparency manually to rgba(253, 0, 0, 0.48) I can still darken it back with the SCSS function, like so:

```
$red: rgba(253, 0, 0, 0.48);
.my-darker-color{
   color: darken($red, 20%); //produces rgba(151, 0, 0, 0.48) close to #990000
}
```

Now, here is the thing. If I lower the transparency even lower, I get more transparency back as a result.

My plan here is to darken a complete transparent variable (doesn't matter which color it produces. I assume dark gray or black), like this:

```
$color0: transparent;
.my-darker-color{
   color: darken($color0, 80%); //give me anything...just not a transparency
}
```

Why doesn't the darken SCSS function work in transparent values?

Comment: How do you want to make transparency darken? It's nothing. Nothing cannot be darken or lighten. If you want, you can use RGBA for semi-transparent colours.

Comment: Well, technically the transparent color renders in the browser as rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) which it can be darken. For example rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); is 15% darker

Comment: It's transparent for you. I didn't see the algorithm of this two functions. However, it may be not a bug.

Comment: _"transparent color renders in the browser as rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"_. Yes, but when you use `transparent` keyword in SASS you are not in the browser and SASS calculates: `transparent: 80% more dark  = transparent`

Answer (score 1):

The `transparent` color value is meant more as a reference than an actual color. The browser translates it to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` but SASS does not support lightening / darkening the reference.

Instead of your current code, simply set `$color0: rgba(0,0,0,0);` - This gives you the same result (transparency), but gives SASS the option to lighten it as needed.

Note that darken / lighten will most likely only affect the initial 3 values - you may end up with `rgba(200,200,200,0)`, which is still transparent. When darkening or lightening this variable in SASS, you want to make sure to also modify the transparency value to make sure it appears.